# Low performance in paralleling SVM structure

Tags: parallel-processing, svm

I have a problem for paralleling a SVM Classification. In my code I repeat 3 times a 5-fold cross validation of SVM and average the accuracy of it. I want to paralell the main loop of 3 times repeat of cross validation but when I use parfor in this loop the program doesn't use all performance of 2 Cores of my CPU and only use 60% of the performance!.

Thank you so much

Code :

```
parfor L=1:NumOFLoops;

indices = crossvalind('Kfold',QQ,NumOfKfold);
cp = classperf(QQ);

for m=1:NumOfKfold;

test = (indices == m); Train = ~test;
testI=zeros(numel(test>0),1);

TrainInputs=INPUT(Train,:);
TrainTargets=QQ(Train,:);
TestInputs=INPUT(test,:);

%% SVM Structure

  svmstruct=svmtrain(TrainInputs,TrainTargets,...
 'boxconstraint',Penalty,...
 'kernel_function','rbf','method','QP',...
 'rbf_sigma',Sigma)

  TestOutputs=svmclassify(svmstruct,TestInputs,'showplot',false);
  classperf(cp,TestOutputs,test);

end
Error(:,L)=cp.ErrorRate;         
end
Results.ErrorRate=(sum(Error))/NumOFLoops;
```